# What constraints do we get on the matrices $A,B$ when we require $AV=VB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

The matrices $A$ and $B$ are, a priori, general unitary $3\times3$ matrices and $V$ is some *fixed* unitary $3\times3$ matrix. When I impose the following requirement on $A$ and $B$:
\begin{equation}
AV = VB \,,
\end{equation}
then what constraints will follow for the matrices $A$ and $B$? They still have to be unitary, PLUS they are not allowed to depend on the fixed parameters of $V$.

My conjecture is that the above requirement will give $A = B = e^{i \alpha}$ (where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$), but how would I prove this?

(The *fixed* matrix $V$ reads: 
\begin{equation}
V = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
c_{12} c_{13} & s_{12} c_{13} & s_{13} e^{-i \delta} \\
- s_{12} c_{23} - c_{12} s_{23} s_{13} e^{i \delta} & c_{12} c_{23} - s_{12} s_{23} s_{13} e^{i \delta} & s_{23} c_{13} \\
s_{12} s_{23} - c_{12} c_{23} s_{13} e^{i \delta} & - c_{12} s_{23} - s_{12} c_{23} s_{13} e^{i \delta} & c_{23} c_{13}
\end{array} \right) \,,
\end{equation}
where $c_{ij} \equiv \cos \theta_{ij}$, $s_{ij} \equiv \sin \theta_{ij}$ and $\theta_{12}, \theta_{23}, \theta_{13}, \delta \in \mathbb{R}$.)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For $B$ a fixed unitary matrix, define the unitary matrix-valued function $f_B(\theta_{12},\theta_{23},\theta_{13},\delta) := VBV^\ast$. What you want to find is $B$ such that $f_B$ is a constant function, in which case, necessarily, $A$ is the constant value of $f_B$. To do so, I'm not sure I can imagine anything other than writing out the constraints
$\frac{\partial f_B}{\partial \theta_{12}} = 0$, $\frac{\partial f_B}{\partial \theta_{23}} = 0$, $\frac{\partial f_B}{\partial \theta_{13}} = 0$, $\frac{\partial f_B}{\partial \delta} = 0$, 
and seeing what they imply for $B$.

Comment: Saying $A$ and $B$ do not depend on a _fixed_ value $V$ makes no sense. If nothing varies, then everything is independent of the (absent) variations of that value.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is equivalent to $A=VBV^*$ (where $V^*=V^{-1}$ since everything is unitary) and to $B=V^*AV$. If you plug *any* unitary $B$ into this equation, out comes a unitary $A$ (because unitary matrices form a group), and vice versa. So you get no constraint whatsoever on $A$ or $B$ individually, although each one determines the other completely.

Comment: Thank you Marc for your quick and clear reply! I forgot to add one constraint though: $A$ and $B$ are not allowed to depend on the fixed parameters of $V$. I will add this to the original question for clarity. How would you solve the problem in this case?

Comment: For $B$ a fixed unitary matrix, define the unitary matrix-valued function $f_B$(\theta_{12},\theta_{23},\theta_{13},\delta) := VBV^\ast$; what you want to find is $B$ such that $f_B$ is constant, in which case, necessarily, $A$ is the constant value of $f_B$. To do so, I'm not sure I can imagine anything else than writing out the constraints
$$
 \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{12}}f_B = 0, \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{23}}f_B = 0, \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{13}}f_B = 0, \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial \delta}f_B = 0,
$$
and seeing what they imply for $B$.